# Structure initialization in class objects

Tags: c++

How do I initialize the structure variables of type class objects? I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class bitmap {
      public :
         bitmap() { clear() ;}
         get();

         set();
         clear();

     static const int a=10;

};

bitmap::get() { 

 };


struct bitmap_list {

       bitmap_list_value         _value;
}

int main()
{

       bitmap bitmap_list_value;

       bitmap_list bbbb;
       bbbb. _value=bitmap_list_value.a;

       cout << bbbb._value << endl;

}
```

Is this code correct, or is it possible to initialize the structure containing the class objects? This is the error I receive:

```
 >error: ‘struct error: ‘_bitmap_list_value’ does not name a type
 >error:bitmap_list’ has no member named ‘_value’
```

Comment: You are also  missing a ; from the bitmap_list declaration...

Comment: Perhaps you meant `struct bitmap_list { int _value;}` ?

Answer (score 3):

No, this code is not correct. You're referencing a type `bitmap_list_value` which is never declared.

Based on your comment ("bitmap_list_value is object of class bitmap"), it sounds as if you also have this, but haven't included it in your question's code for some reason:

```
typedef bitmap bitmap_list_value;
```

But yes, of course you can include members of class types inside `struct`s. A `struct` is more or less a `class` with all fields made `public` by default, you can define methods inside `structs` just as you can with classes, and so on.

Comment: bitmap_list_value is object of class bitmap

Comment: and my question is is it possible to declare class objects inside structure ?

Comment: yes you were correct , I forgot to use typedef . but how to access and store the class member variables in structure containing class objects